# Struggling postdoc Physics

Tags: postdocs, career-path, early-career

I am seeking some career advice on my situation.

I am around my third year of my first postdoc in Physics.

Haven’t published a first author paper for three years now.

I come from a poor immigrant family.

Despite this, I have managed to get into top 5 European bachelors and PhD programs.

I was quite good at high school: could solve math and physics problems without much studying (though not at a genius level of international olympiads folks).

But I have been struggling since I have started university. I have had a really hard time improving: this had a big hit on my already low self esteem (and I will not talk about how lack of money had also a really big impact on me).

Today, people that I did not consider smart enough, and people that I considered smarter than me, are getting ahead of me in their academic career, and know what they are going for.

I love science. I have ideas. I understand things quite quickly.

But to stay in science I have to publish. Something it seems I am not capable of (I am currently stuck on all of my projects, and there are some collaboration deadlines, circling around the same topics).

It seems like I can not make progress.

I actually was on the verge of leaving academia after my PhD. But the fear of missing out (and also of proving to myself and people that I am smart enough to make it in academia) made me stay.

I have to be rational.

I might not be suit for this kind of field, or for technical stuff.

But I also do not want to give up.

I am reconsidering again my cards.

But not sure what to do at this point. And I do not have the courage to talk to my academic supervisors (one of which already considers me a failure).

Comment: You haven't said anything about why you haven't published. It is very difficult to give any advice but to publish. Do you have adequate support in your postdoc, for example? Have you submitted papers that were rejected?

Comment: No rejected papers. Usually what I publish is high quality. But I just struggle to have consistent progress to show to collaborators as others. And struggle to make progress on simple things that I know how to do. But just can go ahead…

Comment: As a wild guess, your focus on smart, smart, smart in your post makes me think that you might be one of those people who relied on their smarts as far as they could and then got stuck once this strategy no longer worked for them. In contrast, people who learn early on that understanding stuff deeply involves working hard instead of just being smart (because they were not so "smart") end up outperforming them.

Comment: I think this point related to my low self esteem makes lots of sense actually. Thanks.

Comment: Just know that as the kind of person you describe yourself as, you'll be very welcome in a lot of companies. Often, it doesn't even matter what your PhD is in. You have one, which distinguishes you from a lot of applicants. So you could choose what kind of work you want to be doing and use this as a way to make some yummy lemon juice out of those lemons :)

Comment: I don't have my thoughts about this in order enough for an answer, but initial thoughts: if you find you can't work as fast as your peers, you've learnt something actionable about yourself, and can adjust your career plans accordingly, e.g. 1. work on problems others aren't paying attention to, so you're not constantly getting scooped; 2. in future, don't agree to inflexible deadlines in your collaborations.

Comment: I suspect you stayed in academia for the wrong reasons. You wrote about fear of missing out, but no matter what you choose in life, you will miss out on something else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your post and comment suggest that your issues aren't technical, but psychological. You might benefit from scheduling a few sessions with a mental health professional with whom you can discuss this. I went through a period of burn-out and I also suffered from extreme introversion. A pro helped me with the latter, but I had to change the situation to get past the burn-out. But someone with experience in counseling academics knows about these and other common issues and can probably provide you with a plan.

Many (most?) universities have a way to provide such help. It won't hurt to talk, and might help.

Comment: Thank you for your point of view. I have not actually considered burned out. I had one during high school. I will consider this.

Comment: Another common malady is Imposter Syndrome.

Answer (score 6):

I am no psychologist, and I would not try to diagnose you, but your story reminds me a bit of myself. I discovered late in life--about the time I finished my PhD--that I have ADHD. I always thought that people with ADHD could not focus; but it turned out that hyper-focus is actually a symptom. I could really focus on my academic work... that is, until things were not going so well. I had some major setbacks in my program. And my ADHD kicked in really hard, and I had a very difficult time keeping myself going. It's been a year since I graduated, and I still have not published anything. I have projects, sure. But I bounce around too much, and I am too perfectionistic about my work. I get overwhelmed by the massive vision of what it would take to "adequately" develop what I want to develop. And yes, I do often feel like a failure in comparison with others. However, I have learned some ways to cope, and I try to keep working on my research, even if it doesn't look like the path others take. And I remind myself that I have something to offer that others who think more neurotypically might not. So, for what it's worth...

Comment: Quite similar to me. Scary. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

All the other issues aside, which have been touched on by others, the most important thing that needs to be addressed ASAP is talking to your advisors. Do not make any assumptions about what your advisors think of you or how they will act, especially if you are in a mental state that is currently very self-deprecating.

Most any reasonable advisor wants their students and postdocs to succeed. Talk to them, explain where you currently are and what some of your current struggles are, both long-term, and project specific. It is their role to guide you through it.

Then start making a plan. Set small goals. Publish some average instead of stellar papers just to get back into it. I think momentum is often more important than that one glossy article, especially for a struggling student/postdoc.

As an advisor, there's nothing that disappoints me more than group members who do not communicate and let things build up to a breaking point, when in reality it could have been easily resolved, together.